# regex- Remove repeated letters in Arabic text by StringToWordVector filter

Tags: java, regex, arabic

I want to remove repeated Arabic letters in my text. How can I do this using regex in Java? I've tried different regex but it removes all the Arabic letters from my text! help plz. 
BTW, I am using regex with StringToWordVector filter like what happening in [here](http://www.giombetti.com/2016/03/06/using-a-regular-expression-to-specify-stop-words-in-weka-machine-learning-from-java/)

This how I applied it:
`filter.setStopwordsHandler(new RegExStopwords("([^\\u1F600-\\u1F6FF\\s].*|[A-Za-z0-9].*|[٠-٩].*|[\\u0617-\\u061A\\u064B-\\u0652].*|[ؐ-ًؚٟ].*|[/(آ|إ|أ)/g, 'ا']|[/(ة)/g, 'ه']|[/(ئ|ؤ)/g, 'ء']|[/(ى)/g, 'ي']|[/([^\\u0621-\\u063A\\u0641-\\u064A\\u0660-\\u0669])/g, '']"));` So I tried the answers mentioned with .replaceAll() function but it did not work with me, or actually I did not know how to fit them in my code correctly.

Comment: This is what worked with me with string variable `.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1")` but I do not know how to apply it to the filter?

Answer (score 0):

I would more readily use a loop

```
String str = "hello"

char prevChar = ' ';
String result = "";
for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
    if(ch != prevChar)
         result += ""+ch //concat casts to string for us
    prevChar = ch
}
```

would return `helo` (with the repeated `l` removed)

**EDIT:**

If you would like to use a filter, the correct regex should be

`/(.)(?<=\1{2,})/ig`

- The first group, `(.)` captures any character
- The next group `(?<=\1{2,})` is broken down as follows:
- `\1` captures the character specified in the first group (`(.)`)
- `{2,}` captures any group that repeats twice
- the `?<=` is a look behind, which basically says we want to check the next term (`\1`) exists, but we don't wish to capture it.

So we're left with only `{2,}` which is captured, which is what you want

For more help, try these Stack Overflow links

- [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)
- [Match Sequence using RegEx After a Specified Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768924/match-sequence-using-regex-after-a-specified-character)

Best of luck!

Comment: but how can I use this with the filter :(

Comment: @Nour_em added to the answer :) hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help,  but it did not work with me :|. I wonder if I did something wrong I don't know! I only added `[]` to the regex to be like this `[/(.)(?<=\1{2,})/ig]` as what I did for the rest of regexes but it did nothing the repeated letters still unremoved!

Comment: @Nour_em, why not use the loop then?