# Extract "Keywords" from a pdf plus the next 200 characters from the keyword in Windows Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powershell script to search a keyword and find from pdf documents, however what i would requires is to get the "Keyword" +  next 200 characters.

The keyword in the below script is "Address" , regex is used to find the keyword. I tried several ways ,but any means I am no expert in this.

Also below script currently giving output in powershell itself , is there a way to get the output in csv format.

Below is the code:

```
$pdflist = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\U6013303\Desktop\Muni Refresh\DOC\old\4295479598" -Filter "*.pdf"

foreach ($pdff in $pdflist){
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\U6013303\Desktop\Muni Refresh\Archives\itextsharp.dll"

$pdffile =  $pdff.Name
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "C:\Users\U6013303\Desktop\Muni Refresh\DOC\old\4295479598\$pdffile"

Write-Host "Reading file $pdffile" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
    $strategy = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'        
    $currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy);
    [string[]]$Text += [system.text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::Convert( [system.text.encoding]::default  , [system.text.encoding]::UTF8, [system.text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($currentText)));  
}

$Text
[regex]::matches( $text, '(Address)' ) | select *

$reader.Close()
}
```

Thanks,
Garry

Answer (score 0):

Simple change to your regex:

```
$results = [regex]::matches($text, 'Address.{200}')
```

Export to CSV:

```
$results | ConvertTo-Csv

# or

$results | Export-Csv -Path "c:\your-path\results.csv"
```

Or if you want just the actual values:

```
$results | select -ExpandProperty Value
```

Comment: Hello @marsze ,The exporting part works , however $results = [regex]::matches($text, 'Address.{200}') still isn't giving results. Thanks.

Comment: @JungleBoy The regex should work just fine, but without an example of your data I am not able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this to see the change you need to make.

```
$Data = "
Match Sequence using RegEx After a Specified Character ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768924/match...
You have the correct regex only the tool you're using is highlighting the entire match and not just your capture group. Hover over the match.
"

[regex]::matches( $Data, 'You').value
# Results
<#
You
#>


[regex]::matches( $Data, 'You.{50}').value
# Results
<#
You have the correct regex only the tool you're using
#>


[regex]::matches( $Data, 'You.{100}').value
# Results
<#
You have the correct regex only the tool you're using is highlighting the entire match and not just you
#>
```

Notice '.Value' property because "[regex]::Matches" does not bring back a single string but an object that you must pick the value property to get the results.